# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)

Tags: php

Alô amigos feras no PHP, alguém pode me ajudar? não consigo descobrir o erro na seguinte função pública:

```
public function addLike($user_id, $tweet_id, $get_id){
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE 'tweets' SET 'likesCount' = 'likesCount' +1 WHERE 'tweetID' = :tweet_id");
        $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        $this-> create('likes', array('likeBy' => $user_id, 'likeOn' => $tweet_id));
    }
```

Se alguém souber o erro e puder ajudar, eu agradeço. Abraço a todos.

Answer (score 1):

O `public` deve ser utilizado apenas em funções dentro de classes (assim como o `private` e o `protected`), ex.:

```
class Classe {
  public function addLike(){
     // código
  }
}
```

No seu caso, a função não pode ser declarada como `public`. Mais a respeito do assunto você pode consultar a **[documentação oficial](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.visibility.php)**.